# I want to connect websocket through my android application

Tags: java, android, node.js, http, websocket

I created a websocket server in node.js and express
here it is:

```
    const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const socketIo = require('socket.io');

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIo(server);

const port = 1338;

io.on('connection', (socket)=>{
    console.log(`A User Connected with ID = ${socket.id}, IP = ${socket.handshake.address}`);

    socket.on('chat', (msg)=>{
        io.emit('chat',msg);
        console.log(msg);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', ()=>{
        console.log("User Disconnected");
    });
});
server.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log("server listening on "+ port);
});
```

Now I want to create a android app which connects this server:
here is my android code:

```
package com.example.chat_websocket;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;
import okhttp3.WebSocket;
import okhttp3.WebSocketListener;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button send_btn;
TextView chat_message;
EditText edit_message;
OkHttpClient okHttpClient;
WebSocket webSocket;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    send_btn = findViewById(R.id.send);
    chat_message = findViewById(R.id.chat_message);
    edit_message = findViewById(R.id.message);

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
             okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("ws://192.168.0.137:1338")
                    .build();
             webSocket = okHttpClient.newWebSocket(request, new ChatWebSocketListner());
            if (webSocket!=null){
                Log.e("WebSocket", "webSocket created successfully");

            }else {
                Log.e("WebSocket", "webSocket creation failed");
            }
            return null;
        }
    }.execute();




    send_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.e("button", "clicked");
            String myMsg = edit_message.getText().toString();
            webSocket.send(myMsg);

        }
    });
}
private class ChatWebSocketListner extends WebSocketListener {

    @Override
    public void onOpen(@NonNull WebSocket webSocket, @NonNull Response response) {
        super.onOpen(webSocket, response);
        Log.e("WebSocket", "Connection opened");
    }

    @Override
    public void onClosed(@NonNull WebSocket webSocket, int code, @NonNull String reason) {
        super.onClosed(webSocket, code, reason);
        Log.e("WebSocket", "Connection CLosed: "+reason);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(@NonNull WebSocket webSocket, @NonNull String text) {
        super.onMessage(webSocket, text);
        displayMessage(text);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull WebSocket webSocket, @NonNull Throwable t, @Nullable Response response) {
        super.onFailure(webSocket, t, response);
        Log.e("WebSocket", "Connection Failed: "+t.getMessage());
    }

    public void displayMessage(final String msg){
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                chat_message.append(msg+"\n");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

}

Now I am getting error in one of my phone :
**E/WebSocket: Connection Failed: unexpected end of stream on http://192.168.0.137:1338/...**
and getting error in another phone:
**Connection Failed: failed to connect to /192.168.0.137 (port 3000) from /192.168.0.12 (port 40040) after 10000ms**

**NOte: I am able to connect to this server on POSTMAN**

i want to know where i am doing mistake as I am trying to learn websocket connection